# Is it possible to connect an antenna of the proper length to a CPU and radiate its 4 GHz oscillating current?

Tags: digital-logic, frequency, cpu, sine, radiation

Since a 4 GHz CPU has been made to provide that super high frequency, is it possible to connect an antenna of the right length to it and radiate its 4 GHz oscillating current?

Comment: Assuming the clock frequency was exposed on an external wire you could do whatever you wanted with it. Transmitting it would probably be illegal though since you'd be interfering with other radios.

Comment: Please indicate which CPU has an external pin producing 4 GHz?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: This clock would be capable of micro-Watts emission at best.  Consuming some of that power [as radiated energy] could cause the CPU to malfunction.  It needs that clock, unadulterated, to fully advance states/registers/micro-ops.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the CPU has a pin that outputs a 4GHz frequency and you connect a suitable antenna to it, it will radiate 4GHz.

You don't need a CPU for that; you can also use some other device that oscillates at 4GHz. Probably very similar to whatever they use for 2.4GHz and 5GHz Wi-Fi.

Whether current CPUs have 4GHz pins, that's questionable. There are lots of different clocks inside and around a CPU and none of them is "the" clock. Each core has a clock; the bus between the cores has a clock; the GPU has a clock; the memory interface has a clock; the [DMI bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Media_Interface) has a clock. [DDR5 memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR5_SDRAM) clocks go up to 3.2GHz.