# Will a pair of identical conductors in the form of identical waves that are 180 degrees out of phase cancel each other out completely?

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, signal, differential, cpu

Since identical waveforms that are 180 degrees out of phase will cancel each other out completely, does that mean a pair of identical conductors in the form of identical waves that are 180 degrees out of phase will cancel each other out completely?

This part of my question

> does that mean a pair of identical conductors in the form of identical
> waves that are 180 degrees out of phase will cancel each other out
> completely?

came to my mind because I'm thinking that a differential pair in a CPU is a pair of identical conductors in the form of identical waves that are 180 degrees out of phase.

I've seen this as an image for the differential pair in the CPU:

[image]

[image]

Also I asked this question [Is it possible to connect an antenna of the proper length to a CPU and radiate its 4 GHz oscillating current?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/660663/is-it-possible-to-connect-an-antenna-of-the-proper-length-to-a-cpu-and-radiate-i)
in an other website and someone posted those images and said:

> Not only this cancels radiation by signal but also cancels external
> noise. Waves are here to make this trace pair as long as other trace
> pair.

Comment: Completely is such a strong word. Nothing in physical world is ideal. So basically, your question could be answered with a "no". But can you improve the question by expanding it by what are you asking with this, to expand the answer with an explanation?

Comment: Electrical waves (voltages and currents), and mechanical waves (meandering traces) are two very different kinds of waves!  The traces are constructed here in such a way that the mechanical wave has little to no effect on the electrical waves.

Comment: If your signal is a electromagnetic wave then you do get cancellation of the wave. This manifests as diffraction, Young's two slit and interferometers and perhaps all of optics.

Comment: **To the OP**: the question appears to be asking if the two identical conductors will cancel out. Clearly that cannot happen so, be very clear about what you are asking to avoid ambiguity. I've read your question body a couple of times now and I still don't know what you want to know. You also refer to an earlier question you raised and, in that question, I made a comment that you didn't respond to. This doesn't help get you answers. Despite that, you received an answer so, explain why that answer doesn't help you. Please link to the source of your pictures.

Comment: Conductors cannot cancel out. Conductors are material. In effect your question asks if conductors cancel out and, clearly, that is impossible.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what a differential pair is. The wavelike structure is not essential to making it a differential pair; the fact that the signals on the two wires are differential, and they're kept at a constant controlled distance from each other, is. The wavelike structure is just to adjust the total length of it, to make signal propagation times match between multiple differential pairs.

Comment: The wavy track is not two waves out of phase, it is just waving to make the track longer so it is the same length as the other tracks

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your question is why do the signals carried by the differential pair not cancel each other out?

Two waveforms that are identical  will cancel each other at the physical points in space where they are 180 degrees out of phase. You see this, for example, on an open-circuited transmission line, where the combination of the incident signal and the reflected signal from the open-circuit produces a standing wave with periodic nulls along the length of the transmission line.

In the case of a differential pair, the signal is being guided by the two parallel conductors. There isn't a separate signal 180 degrees out of phase that will cause destructive interference. It is more like when you swap the leads of a multimeter taking a DC measurement and the result reads negative. There is really only one signal on the differential pair, but it will look flipped around depending on which line is taken as the reference.